# How to connect React with Django?

Tags: django, reactjs

My team has decided to use React for the frontend and Django for the backend.

What is the correct way to link Django and React? Do I just put my React files in the Django template folder?

Comment: [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)  is your friend!

Comment: I think you should use Django Rest Framework to build API for your React WebApp.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for this. It allows you to create JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) APIs using Django. This means that your Django/ python models now can be interacted with using javascript. Now you can use React to do things like query data in your database (through your Django models) and display it on your frontend.

It also gives the the added bonus of allowing you to use any frontend framework that reads JSON (most of them do). For example, you can now build an iPhone app using another frontend framework and use the same Django API that you're using with React as its backend. This means you only need to have one backend framework to serve all of your frontend projects.

Comment: So after installing DRF, letting Django interact with the .js file, can I use the React file as a template just as I would do with existing Django .html?
But, how can I apply Django's syntax to the .js files React spits out?

Comment: It's only javascript codes, It can be applied like html?

Comment: Why do you need Django syntax in the React file? The frontend logic e.g. for loops etc can be coded using javascript when you've set up React. Sorry, I might be misunderstanding you question

Comment: It don't need to link Django's Model.py & Views.py with React .js files?

Comment: They link through the serialiser you set up with Django REST. I think the best thing would be to follow a tutorial or a course on how to setup Django REST with React and you will see what I mean. Its too much information to convey through Stackoverflow I'm afraid.